# Output multiple plots to file in R

Tags: r, file, pdf, plot

I am trying to plot two graphs side by side and save them to file. Here is my code below. The problem is that I cannot control margins. Whatever margin I enter, they are not reflected in the file.

In general is there any tutorial on how to print nicely to file in R. I am reading through all manuals and examples, but it is not too clear. When I print, things are getting distorted in very interesting fashion, I do not recall having same trouble in Matlab or Python. R has tones of degrees of freedom.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

sample_df <- data.frame(col_1=c(1,2,3), col_2=c(6,7,8))
plot_1 <-ggplot(data=sample_df, aes(x = col_1, y =col_2, group=1))+
  geom_line()+ggtitle('Title 1')
plot_2 <-ggplot(data=sample_df, aes(x = col_1, y =col_2, group=1))+
  geom_line()+ggtitle('Title 2')

width_letter = 6
height_letter = width_letter*8.5/11

pdf('outpdf_1.pdf', width=width_letter, height=height_letter)
par(mai=c(3.02,0.82,0.82,0.42))
grid.arrange(plot_1, plot_2, ncol=2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Did you try setting the margins _before_ you plot the graphs?

Comment: @G5W, I tried, it did not work. Margin seem to work fine, if I replace `grid.arrange` with simple `plot` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cowplot package. The plot.margin inside of the theme function allows margins to be set. Here's an example with 2cm margins on each of the four sides:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)

sample_df <- data.frame(col_1=c(1,2,3), col_2=c(6,7,8))
plot_1 <-ggplot(data=sample_df, aes(x = col_1, y =col_2, group=1))+
  geom_line()+ggtitle('Title 1')
plot_2 <-ggplot(data=sample_df, aes(x = col_1, y =col_2, group=1))+
geom_line()+ggtitle('Title 2')

width_letter = 6
height_letter = width_letter*8.5/11

pdf('outpdf_1.pdf', width=width_letter, height=height_letter)
plot_grid(plot_1, plot_2, labels = "AUTO", ncol = 2, align = 'v') +   
 theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2,2,2,2), "cm")) 

dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, I wonder if can adjust size of axis on my plot, it looks pretty ugly right now

Comment: You are welcome. Ugly, like statistics, is objective if we give good arguments. That said, opening another question may be the best way to get an answer to your question about adjusting axes.